# excel: make SUM.IF work with formulas

Tags: excel, excel-2010, libreoffice-calc

On excel I have a

```
=SOMME.SI(B$10:B248;B7;L$10:L248)
```

B7 contain "a", L$x:L$y has values to sum

If the zone `B$10:B248`: has "a" or "b" that work very well.

But if the zone `B$10:B248`: has a formula with an IF:

```
SI("zf"=M18;"a";"?")
```

That did not work any more, how can I explain to excel/calc that

```
SI("zf"=M18;"a";"?") should be == "a"
```

in case the if conditions is true ?

Comment: Does `B7` contain `"a"` or `a`? If it's `a` both constant values and values returned by IF should work exactly the same.

Comment: in all case B7 contain "a", the Pb is when B$10:B$XX contain a calculated result "a" through IF("zf"=M18;"a";"?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark is a wildcard. By referencing it as the criteria, you are telling SUMIFS to accept any single character. You are going to have to change the `?` to something else to avoid wildcard matches.

[image: sumif_wildcard]

Comment: Or you could turn off regular expressions in formulas: Tools→Options→LibreOffice Calc→Calculate→UNcheck the box for "Enable regular expressions in formulas"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, to get `"a"` in cell when `IF` formula returns `TRUE`, you should use below formula

```
=SI("zf"=M18;"a";"?")
```

as

```
=SI("zf"=M18;"""a""";"?")
```

You can also use:

```
=SI(M18="zf",CHAR(34) & "a" & CHAR(34),"?")
```

**Note**: CHAR(34) returns the double quote character `"`